# Passing double[] from Java to JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying to pass some arguments to JavaScript. I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". So I am assuming I didn't pass it correctly. Here's the code.

```
var a, b, doubles;
function init() {
    a = JSInterface.getXValue();
    b = JSInterface.getYValue();

    doubles = JSInterface.getDoublesValue();
    for (i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Now, I get the 'a' and 'b' values correctly, but not the 'doubles'. Java:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(x, y, nums), "JSInterface");
```

Both x and y are of type double and nums is double[].

I'll also put JSInterface:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    double x, y;
    double[] nums;

    JavaScriptInterface(double x, double y, double[] nums) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.nums = nums;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public double getXValue() {
        return x;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public double getYValue() {
        return y;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public double[] getDoublesValue() {
        return nums;
    }
}
```

I am obviously doing something wrong with passing the third argument, yes?

Comment: Could you please provide the stack trace of the Error

Comment: Well it's an Android app, I am giving you the LogCat which says, as already mentioned, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at file:///android_asset/myScript.js:24" which is the line of "for (i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {".

Comment: Looks like you itialize nums with null or something like that, maybe use the debugger and find out which value the nums has you pass to the JavaSCriptInterface's constructor

Comment: Nums in Java before I call WebView line has 6 double values :/